# Execute different code upon second click (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

My problem is that I've been working on a "accordion menu", which uses CSS3 transition on the height property to give it an animation when the `<li>` is expanding, which contains a submenu.

The expansion of the `<li>` happens when calling a function, triggered by a onclick event.
The function calculates the new height for the containing `<li>` based on how many `<li>'s` the submenu contains. All this works fine, but I can't figure out how to reset the height on the second click, to close the submenu.

```
function accordion(ul){
    {
    // Make new height happen
    var howManyChildren = document.getElementById(ul).children.length;
    var calcSubHeight = 30 + howManyChildren * 31 + 'px'; // "top-padding" + amount of <li>'s * each <li> height + unit
    var elementId = ul.replace('_ul','');
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.height = subHeight;
    }
    else // Code to be executed on secound click.
    {
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.height = "";
    }
}
```

I want the "else" block to execute on the second click, as the comment states.
So I might have been a bit to elaborate here. And pardon for the bad English, I'm quite Swedish.

Comment: If your making an accordion box then you probably want an answer that toggles the height state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it sees if the height returns false.

```
function accordion(ul) {
    var elementId = ul.replace('_ul', '');
    if (!document.getElementById(elementId).style.height) {
        var howManyChildren = document.getElementById(ul).children.length;
        var calcSubHeight = 30 + howManyChildren * 31 + 'px'; // "top-padding" + amount of <li>'s * each <li> height + unit
        document.getElementById(elementId).style.height = subHeight;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(elementId).style.height = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! except I made a error when translating the code, on line 6, it should be "calcSubHeight" instead of "subHeight". Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether it's the first or second click, you'll need to keep a variable that changes on each click. A closure is ideal for this:

```
var accordion = ( function accordionClosure(){
    var count = 0;

    return function accordion( ul ){
        if ( count === 0 ){
            var howManyChildren = document.getElementById(ul).children.length;
            var calcSubHeight = 30 + howManyChildren * 31 + 'px'; // "top-padding" + amount of <li>'s * each <li> height + unit
            var elementId = ul.replace('_ul','');
            document.getElementById(elementId).style.height = subHeight;

            count = 1;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(elementId).style.height = "";

            count = 0;
        }
    };
}() );
```